# PHP & cURL & Windows Vista

Tags: php, curl, windows-vista

Having issues using cURL on windows vista. The library is there and showing with phpinfo(), but curl_exec() is not returning the web page content - when uploaded and tested on a linux server there's no problems with the same code, returns the data as expected.

Does anyone have any experience with this/ideas? I'm using xampp and php 5.2.6.

**UPDATE:**

```
Array( [url] => https://graph.facebook.com/me
    [content_type] => [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.203
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0 )
```

Is the response I get from print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));

Comment: It might be a windows firewall issue...can you paste your code here, and the output when run from the command line?

Comment: I just included an update with what curl is doing. I've disabled windows firewall and it made no difference.

Comment: Also, running from GIT BASH, curl -L https://www.google.com works fine.

Comment: When I go to https://graph.facebook.com/me in a browser, I get this JSON response: {
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
   }
}

How are you authenticating your request?

Comment: AJ - the authentication isn't the problem, I don't get any JSON or anything back.

Comment: @William Steward - tell you what...if you can paste all of your curl code here, I'd be happy to troubleshoot on my end and see what results I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that's a `https` address.

Try doing this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Setting that to false allows `Curl` to accept any `CA`.

You can check the documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**
>   FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST may also need to be TRUE or FALSE if CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is disabled (it defaults to 2).

Comment: Wow, thanks that's great. Fixed it! I wonder why they don't include that in the standard facebook php sdk? I guess it has security set backs potentially if the facebook site was attacked.

Comment: Hmmm... this may have fixed it... but.. I would check to see if they have any documentation on how to handle FB SSL and try to use that. This method basically accepts any CA. Which may or may not be secure depending on what you're doing with it.

Comment: I just googled it to check on things. It seems this is a standard fix for your type of error. You should be ok.

Comment: I also just read that it's not "included" because the error depends on what kind of system you're running on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change: `[url] => https://graph.facebook.com/me` to

```
[url] => "https://graph.facebook.com/me"
```

I assume that you are using commas to separate the key-value pairs in php array.

Comment: It would display like this:`array("url" => "https://graph.facebook.com/me");`. `[url] => https://graph.facebook.com/me` is just the printed version using `print_r` or a similar function. Also, the printed data looks like the `CURL_INFO` output to me.